# Using a custom prop with Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using `Formik` in my application and i was wondering how to pass props and values to Sub Pages rendered by `Formik`.

I am implementing `Formik` like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0yzy0lwvn)

I have created a prop called `handleSave`

```
handleSave = (values) => {
  console.log("Save clicked", values);
}
```

and trying to send it to `Formik` like this

```
<form
    handleSave={() => (
        this.handleSave(values);
    )}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    values={values}
>
```

But it was throwing `React does not recognize the`handleSave`prop on a DOM element` error, So, I sent it via `Wiz` and created a prop there in `_renderPage()`, this showed the prop and was clickable but the values weren't updated from `Formik`.

How do i solve it?